# PHP code debugger on the fly

Tags: php, debugging, on-the-fly

i have a website on my localhost, a quite complicated one with many links 
is there a program that can debug for example, what happens when i click one link?or i login, etc
and show me each function called in each file and everything that's happening with the scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eclipse + PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) or [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) with the PHP plugin and then install a recent version of [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/). This will allow you to set breakpoints, inspect variables, etc.

If you want to get an overall view of your script/framework you can use the cachegrind files xdebug is able to produce and then use a viewer for those files (e.g. kcachegrind). This will help you understand how many times a function is called, what the most time consuming parts of your application are, etc..

Comment: Create a new project and import your sources. You need to install xdebug aswell (activate the extension in the php.ini).

Comment: i installed and imported i can see all my files there , but i would like to set up breakpoints on the actual page in a browser, and to see each step that runs in the background of a login operation for example

Answer (score 0):

when i click on test debugger it says A time-out occurred when the debug server attempted to connect to the following client hosts/IPs: 192.168.0.33 and 127.0.0.1

Comment: That is very likely because you didn't setup xdebug. Install it as I already suggested in my answer + comment..